# Is it possible implement an equivalent of data provider in Cypress.io

Tags: node.js, automation, cypress

Is it possible to implement an equivalent of data provider in Cypress.io? I was checking and you can simulate it with a fixture and make a foreach for it but I would like to confirm if is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is **yes**. You can find all examples [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests#examples)

But also there is [data-driven](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bahmutov/data-driven) npm package. All examples you can find [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bahmutov/data-driven#use).

Comment: yes it partly does what dataProvider in webdriver do with the exception of able to run parallel since right now cypress only runs specs in parallel and not the it block